$\mathbb{P}$-names for powersets in forcing extension
So, I am trying to understand how to solve the following:

Take the usual setup for forcing: a poset $\mathbb{P}$ lying in a countable transitive model $\mathcal{M}$. Give an explicit description of $\mathbb{P}$-names for power-sets in the forcing extension: that is, for any $\mathbb{P}$ name $x$, give a $\mathbb{P}$-name $y$ such that in any generic extension $M[G]$,$$(y_G = \mathscr{P}(x_G))^{M[G]},$$ or equivalently, $\mathbf{1} \Vdash y = \mathscr{P}(x)$.

At first, I thought (perhaps naively) that we can take the construction in Kunen of the proof that $M[G]$ satisfies $\sf{ZFC}$ (and in particular power-set), i.e. $\rho = S \times \{\mathbf{1}\}$ in lemma 4.2 VII, and then form the requisite set by comprehension (in $M[G]$). But I am unsure whether this is the correct way? Is this a valid way to do it, or is there another way?

Using separation in $M[G]$ gets you $\mathscr{P}^{M[G]}(x_G)$, but doesn't give a name for it, which is what the question is asking for. We need to apply the required "separation" to $\rho$, which is a name for a superset of $\mathscr{P}^{M[G]}(x_G)$, to make it a name for $\mathscr{P}^{M[G]}(x_G)$.
The idea behind the definition of $\rho=S\times \{1\}$ where $S = \mathscr{P}^M(\operatorname{dom}(x)\times P)$ is that we include everything that could potentially be a subset of $x,$ i.e. all the names in $S.$ In order to not overshoot the power set, we need to be more choosy, and not just include all of them "with probability 1", i.e. our name will be some subset of $S\times P$ we can define in $M$.

 Use the forcing relation... take $\rho' = \{(\tau,p)\in S\times P: p\Vdash\tau\subseteq x\}.$ Now, unlike $\rho,$ this clearly only includes things that will actually be subsets of $x_G$, but you'll need to confirm, modifying the proof for $\rho,$ that it's still large enough that it will always contain every subset.


In fact, there is a slightly different way which doesn't require applying the proof of the selection axiom or theorem for $M[G]$ in constructing the name for $P(x)$ -- although it might end up being needed in showing that that name is correct.
Namely, set $x' := \{ (\tau, q) \in \operatorname{dom}(x) \times \mathbb{P} \mid \exists p \ge q, (\tau, p) \in x \}$, and $y := P^M(x') \times \{ 1 \}$.  It is easy to see that $1 \Vdash x' = x$, so for any subset $\sigma \subseteq x'$, we have $1 \Vdash \sigma \subseteq x$.  This shows that $1 \Vdash y \subseteq P(x)$.  On the other hand, if you have a $\mathbb{P}$-name $\sigma$, then you can show that a name for $x^G \cap \sigma^G$ is $\sigma' := \{ (\tau, q) \in x' \mid q \Vdash \tau \in \sigma \} \in P^M(x')$.  (Depending on the exact construction in the proof of the selection axiom or theorem in $M[G]$, this might even be simply the special case for the selection set $\{ z \in x^G \mid z \in \sigma^G \}$.)  Therefore, in particular, you have $1 \Vdash \sigma \subseteq x \rightarrow \sigma = \sigma'$ as well as $1 \Vdash \sigma' \in y$, and it follows that $1 \Vdash \sigma \subseteq x \rightarrow \sigma \in y$.  Since that holds for all $\mathbb{P}$-names $\sigma$, we conclude $1 \Vdash \forall z, z \subseteq x \rightarrow z \in y$, i.e. $1 \Vdash P(x) \subseteq y$.
